# Проектирование приложения для мониторинга

Tags: c#, datagrid, wpf

Помогите спроектировать интерфейс приложения следующего вида. При запуске программы должна появляться таблица:

```
Название школы
--------------
Школа № 1
Школа № 2
Школа № 3
```

При клике на любую из школ должна появляться таблица:

```
Наименование
------------
Содержание
Условие
Предметные результаты
```

Здесь уже для каждого пункта должна открываться своя таблица. К примеру для "Содержание" должно появится:

```
Наименование
-----------------------
Оценка кадровых условий
Организация углубленного изучения предметов
```

И здесь самое главное, потому что для этих пунктов таблицы будут разными - с разным количеством столбцом. И они уже должны заполняться пользователем. К примеру для "Организация углубленного изучения предметов" таблица выглядит так:

```
Название школы | Критерий 1| Критерий 2|
----------------------------------------
Школа № 1      |     0     |     1     |
```

Значения критерий для подобных таблиц хранятся/редактируются в базе данных. Используется LINQ to Entities. Замучился с пониманием MVVM. Пытался построить без него. Но трудно обойти этот паттерн в WPF - везде все завязано на Binding, а так как конечные таблицы, как вы могли заметить имеют разное количество столбцов, то и Binding получается запутанным.

Я вижу два пути:

1. Использовать один DataGrid и кликая
       по пунктам спускаться по иерархии
       (как в Total)
2. Или слева сделать Tree, а справа
       один DataGrid

Не один из способов ранее не делал. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Как по мне, так второй способ более юзабельный. Только справа надо будет лучше, всё же, не один а разные дата-гриды взять и скрывать их или показывать. Конкретного технического вопроса я не увидел, так что помочь трудно, но могу посоветовать прочитать статью создателя этого шаблона https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/dd419663.aspx. А вообще обойтись и без него можно было бы. Как MVVM-Framework могу посоветовать MVVM Light. Простой и работает.

Comment: Спасибо. Поверьте Вы даже этим помогли. Я сильно мучаюсь, и надо, чтобы хоть кто-то хотя бы в неправильное направление подтолкнул. )

Answer (score 3):

Смотрите. Вам надо отделить логику программы от логики представления.

Делаете так:

1. У вас есть VM-классы, соответствующие (а) корню программы, (б) одной школе, (в) каждому внутреннему пункту в описании школы и т. д.
2. У вас есть несколько View (например, UserControl'ов), каждое их которых отображает какую-то сущность. Например:

   ```
   <UserControl x:Class="RootView" ...>
       <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Schools}">
           <ListView.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:School}">
                   <local:SchoolCollapsedView/>
               </DataTemplate>
           </ListView.ItemTemplate>
       </ListView>
   </UserControl>

   <UserControl x:Class="SchoolCollapsedView" ...>
       <TextBox>
           <Run Text="Школа № "/><Run Text="{Binding Number}"/>
       </TextBox>
   </UserControl>
   ```

   и так далее.
3. Ваша логика программы видит, что надо переключить отображение на, допустим, отображение конкретной школы, и подменяет View в корневом окне, а заодно и его ViewModel.
4. Можно подмену View автоматизировать при помощи правильно выстроенных `DataTemplate`'ов. Считайте это продвинутым заданием, без него вначале можно обойтись. Когда выучите на практике MVVM, будет легко и очевидно.
5. Весь LINQ и обращение к базе данных уходит на модельный уровень. Binding происходит к VM-объектам, а не к объектам базы данных. Не забывайте, что операции с базой данных не стоит проводить в главном потоке, иначе зависаний UI не избежать. Если у вашей базы есть async-интерфейс, пользуйтесь им.